# IE8 Async file upload

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to find example code to upload files asyncronously (via Ajax) in IE8. Also upload progress would be nice, but not mandatory. Id like PHP code to be able to deal with the file server side. I keep coming across examples for other browsers using FormData, but I cannot use that. Could any body please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Seems like a good tutorial: http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-easiest-asynchronous-upload-file-ajax-upload/

Comment: the only option is submitting form via `iframe`

Comment: So its not possible via Ajax??

Comment: This will work like Ajax, in background. But it is not possible exactly with ajax (at least in ie8)

Comment: @Niklas do you want to put that as an answer... I shall accept that as the answer, considering its what I decided to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good tutorial on the subject: http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-easiest-asynchronous-upload-file-ajax-upload/

HTML:

```
<form id="my_form" name="form" action="upload.php" method="POST" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<div id="main">
<input name="my_files" id="my_file" size="27" type="file" />
<input type="button" name="action" value="Upload" onclick="redirect()"/>
<iframe id='my_iframe' name='my_iframe' src="">
</iframe>
</div>

</form>
```

JS:

```
function redirect()
{
//'my_iframe' is the name of the iframe
document.getElementById('my_form').target = 'my_iframe';
document.getElementById('my_form').submit();
}
```

PHP:

```
$uploaddir = '/images/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['my_files']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['my_files']['my_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "success";
} else {
echo "error";
}
```

That will get you started =)

Answer (score 1):

User this http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload jquery plugin..Its best and tested..

Comment: I had used it. It works fine in IE except uploadProgress not worked in IE.