# Prevent iframe popup after performing file upload using a hidden iframe?

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe, internet-explorer-8

Can someone please help me here, I have used a mixture of these two tutorials below to overcome the limits of IE and create an "async upload" via an iframe. Now this all works fine except the issue that seems to occur in IE8 where the return from the .php file posts back to the iframe and opens a new window to display the output in. Is there anything I can do to stop this popup from happening?

[IE8 Async file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514352/ie8-async-file-upload)

http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-easiest-asynchronous-upload-file-ajax-upload/

Thank you all in advance,

Ash.

Comment: How are you hiding the iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) link.

Important notes:

> It is important to note that even when the dataType option is set to 'script', and the server is actually responding with some javascript to a multipart form submission, the response's Content-Type header should be forced to text/html, otherwise Internet Explorer will prompt the user to download a "file".

According to text above - you must force your server side code return Content-Type header set to text/html.

and

> To account for the challenges of script and JSON responses when using the iframe mode, the Form Plugin allows these responses to be embedded in a textarea element and it is recommended that you do so for these response types when used in conjuction with file uploads and older browsers.

Those are notes for jquery plugin which allows to do things you need. But first quote will work for you too. Second is important only if you return JSON or script.